# React Hooks: useState updater function: Why does this hook remove the object upon drag?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-context

I have a marker on a map which takes this function upon dragging:

```
  function handleOnDragEndUpdateMarker(e) {
    var markerIndex = e.target.options.marker_index;
    var markerLatLng = e.target.getLatLng(); //get marker LatLng
    markerLatLng.id = markerIndex;
    updateUserMarker(markerLatLng, markerIndex);
  }
```

That function fires another function `updateUserMarker`, which is coming from a component via context:

It consumes the index, a new object which contains updated `lat` and `long` from the `event`, & appends an `id` which will also be from the event.

In the context component, I have this function:

```
 updateUserMarker: (marker, markerIndex) => {
      console.log('marker, markerIndex ', marker, markerIndex);

      let updatedMarker = user.markers.map(element =>
        element.id == markerIndex ? { ...element, ...marker } : element
      )[0];

      console.log(
        'user.markers[markerIndex] updatedMarker ',
        user.markers[markerIndex],
        updatedMarker
      );
      setUser({
        ...user,
        markers: [
          {
            ...user.markers[markerIndex],
            ...(user.markers[markerIndex] = updatedMarker)
          }
        ]
      });
    },
```

It works fine with the first objects—lat and lang, but upon adding the second object after the dragging commences it disappears!

Probably should have tried to come here hours ago, but wanted to give it my best effort!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you used `[0]` for `updatedMarker`. I assume that you want to update the marker whose id is matched with markerIndex.

```js
updateUserMarker: (marker, markerIndex) => {
  let updatedMarkers = user.markers.map(element =>
    element.id == markerIndex ? { ...element, ...marker } : element
  );
  
  setUser({
    ...user,
    markers: [...updatedMarkers]
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting! Oh `.map` returns an array, so I just wanted to pull the object out e.g.   `[ {id: xxx, lat:xxx, lng:xxx} ] = user.markers.map(...map function..)[0]`.

Comment: Thank YOU!!!!!!!  I should have done this hours ago! Happy holidays!